# Count rows containing zeros between consecutive numbers in matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to rename zeros between consecutive numbers in rows of a column. For example, I need output A to look like output Anew.

> > A = [1, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 4]

A =

```
 1     0     0     0     2     0     3     0     0     0     0     0     4
```

> > Anew = [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4]

Anew =

```
 1     1     1     1     2     2     3     3     3     3     3     3     4
```

Any help would be very much appreciated and thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If they are consecutive positive numbers you can use `cummax`:

```
Anew = cummax(A) ;
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace zeros with `NaN`s and then use [`fillmissing`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html) to replace `NaN`s with the previous non-`NaN` value.

```
Anew = A;
Anew(Anew==0) = NaN; 
Anew = fillmissing(Anew,'previous');
```

or as a one-liner using [`standardizeMissing`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/standardizemissing.html) with [`fillmissing`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fillmissing.html):

```
Anew = fillmissing(standardizeMissing(A,0),'previous');
```